# What is the purpose of and how to use the xreg argument when fitting ARIMA model in R?

Tags: r, time-series, multivariate-analysis, arima

I am really new with R and time series. But, I have understood most concept. Part where I am (very) confused is the `xreg=` argument in `arima()` from [tseries](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tseries/index.html) package and [forecast](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/index.html) package. As I have read most of the related threads on this site, I understand that `xreg` is used for exogenous data. See for example, [How to fit an ARIMAX-model with R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18375/how-to-fit-an-arimax-model-with-r).

Thus, I conclude that I can fit SARIMAX or ARMAX method using `arima()`. However, I am currently reading Shumwhay's book and his web [tutorial](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/R_time_series_quick_fix.htm).

If you check the website (close to the bottom of the page), you can found that he said

> `xreg` in `arima()` does not fix ARMAX model.

It is also explained in the [R issues](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/Rissues.htm) on his website. In addition, he proposed fitting ARMAX model in state space model. So, the answers found on this site and the explanation in the website are completely different.

Can anyone explain me why there is such discrepancy? Which one is correct?

If Shumwhay is correct, is there any function/package that can fit ARMAX or SARIMAX model in R?

Sorry if it turns out I only missed some points, but I hope you can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 12):

An ARMAX model simply adds in the covariate on the right hand side of the usual ARMA equation:
$$
y_t = \beta x_t + \phi_1 y_{t-1} + \cdots + \phi_p y_{t-p} - \theta_1 z_{t-1} - \dots - \theta_q z_{t-q} + z_t
$$
where $z_t$ is white noise, $x_t$ is a covariate at time $t$ and $\beta$ is its coefficient. There is no R function that fits exactly this model, although the transfer function model implemented by the TSA package is similar (the above model is a transfer function model but with a parameter constraint).

The model used by `arima()` and `auto.arima()` with an `xreg` argument is a linear regression with ARMA errors:
\begin{align*}
y_t &= \beta x_t + n_t\\
n_t &= \phi_1 n_{t-1} + \cdots + \phi_p n_{t-p} - \theta_1 z_{t-1} - \dots - \theta_q z_{t-q} + z_t
\end{align*}

For more details, see my [blog post](http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/arimax/) on the various models and how they are related.

Comment: @ Rob Hyndman.. I have realized it yesterday, but your explanation made it much clearer..thank you very much..btw, I love your work on the package..thank you for all the lectures and explanation on it..I am reading it along with shumwhay's book..I didn't expect my question would be answered by you from all people,,