# When using the exreg argument in auto.arima in R, is the main series still being used as a predictor?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

[What is the purpose of and how to use the xreg argument when fitting ARIMA model in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25780/what-is-the-purpose-of-and-how-to-use-the-xreg-argument-when-fitting-arima-model)

My question relates to how the xreg argument is working when fitting an ARIMA model (purpose of xreg described in the post above.)

```
library(forecast)
fity <- auto.arima(y, xreg=x)
```

In the code above, is the ARIMA model being fit using past values of $y$ as predictors as well as the past values of $x$? i.e. is it assumed that the past $y$ values would be used as they would be if running an ARIMA modelling without an explanatory variable $x$? Or if I use $\text{xreg} = x$ and want the $y$ series to be used as predictors, would I have to add $y$ to the xreg matrix to force that to occur?

Comment: Ah, I think I might understand this better after some thought!  So the regression is done against the x series.  Then the residuals will possibly auto-correlate if there is some sequential structure in the main series that isn't explained by the x series.  Those errors are modelled using ARIMA.  So its equivalent to doing ARIMA on the main series along with a regression on the explanatory variable.

Comment: This might merit a new question but I wonder will this method regress against lagged values of the x series e.g. at lag 1. Or is it only regressing against the x values at the same point in time as the y value.  Would I have to add the x series with a lag 1 into the x matrix to force the method to see if the correlation was occuring at a lag? I might want to do this if I think the x variable is a leading variable (with lag 1).