# ARIMA - SARIMAX modelling with R

Tags: r, modeling, arima, model

I am really new to R and to time series. My field of studies is in the field of Networks and Telecommunication, but my summer internship is about trying to find a statistical model for some sets of data.

The data consists of what is called "10-minutes-points", recorded over a year and which represent power consuption of a source substation. It means I have 6 * 24 * 365 = 52 560 points of data to process, one set for each source substation.

It's been about a week I'm trying to found information about ARIMA models. [This website](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/9) and the report of my predecessor quite helped me getting in the subject, by I still encountered many problems.

I found one might be due to the large size of the data set [as explained here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27313/how-would-you-fit-arima-model-with-lots-of-autocorrelations), the second one to the existence of exogenous data as [mentioned there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25780/what-is-the-purpose-of-and-how-to-use-the-xreg-argument-when-fitting-arima-model).

My predecessor found the ARIMA model to be effective for short term predictions (up to 20-ish hours), and the SARIMAX for mid-term predictions (around a dozen days). I guess it is cause exogeneous data doesn't affect as much the core data on such short periods of time.

I found [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18375/how-to-fit-an-arimax-model-with-r) to be very interesting but I'm not sure I understand everything.

In a first time I would like to know if my understanding of the general method to evaluate a model is correct :

1. first you plot your data and try to look for any trend/seasonality (the data I have showed to have a daily seasonality and a yearly one)
2. you use log in order to reduce the trend, and maybe differentiate to eliminate the seasonality (so I should use something like : `diff(data.ts, 144)` in my case to get rid of the daily seasonality (6*24 points a day) ?)
3. plot the acf/pcf of the differentiated time series and try to estimate a model from there
4. try to fit the model to my data with `fit <- Arima(data, order=c(p,d,q), seasonal=c(P,D,Q))` but I don't where the seasonality (144) would appear in this function ?
5. study the residuals of fit to see if the model is correct (looking at the acf/pacf)
6. use fitted or forecast (I don't know which one is better) to predict future values

Thing is, since the data set is huge, I always get significant spikes at many lags in the acf/pacf and I don't feel I can judge if a model is correct or not.

Here is an example :

`data = scan("auch.txt", skip=1)
plot.ts(data)`

[image: Data]

`data.ts = ts(log(data)
data.diff = diff(data.ts, 144)
plot.ts(data.diff)`

[image: Datadiff]

Which seems somehow stationary to me. I then proceed to look at the acf/pacf, and had to differentiate once more because it wasn't stationary in fact :

`tsdisplay(data.diff, lag.max=150)
tsdisplay(diff(data.diff), lag.max=150)`

[image: Tsdisplay]
[image: Tsdisplaydiff]

And I really don't know how to handle these results, so I hoped I could find some help here, because I came across the website a lot during my researchs.

Thanks in advance, and I apologies for any grammatical mistakes or vocabulary error ; English is not my native language.

**Edit :** does anyone know why my pictures won't appear ?

**Edit bis :** nvm in fact it might be me, because imgur is blocked on my work computer