# ARIMA forecasting with auto.arima() and xreg

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I am working on project to forecast sales of stores to learn forecasting. Until now I have successfully used simple `auto.arima` function for forecasting. But to make these forecast more accurate I can make use of covariates. I have defined covariates like holidays, promotion which affect on sales of store using `xreg` argument with the help of this post:
[How to setup xreg argument in auto.arima() in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41070/how-to-setup-xreg-argument-in-auto-arima-in-r)

But my code fails at line:

```
ARIMAfit <- auto.arima(saledata, xreg=covariates)
```

and gives error saying:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = x ~ xreg, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'xreg')
In addition: Warning message:
In !is.na(x) & !is.na(rowSums(xreg)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Below is link to my Dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-KJYBgmb044blZGSWhHNEoxaHM/view?usp=sharing

This is my code:

```
data = read.csv("xdata.csv")[1:96,]
View(data)

saledata <- ts(data[1:96,4],start=1, end=96,frequency =7 )
View(saledata)

saledata[saledata == 0] <- 1
View(saledata)

covariates = cbind(DayOfWeek=model.matrix(~as.factor(data$DayOfWeek)),
             Customers=data$Customers,
             Open=data$Open,
             Promo=data$Promo,
             SchoolHoliday=data$SchoolHoliday)
View(head(covariates))


# Remove intercept
covariates <- covariates[,-1]
View(covariates)

require(forecast)
ARIMAfit <- auto.arima(saledata, xreg=covariates)//HERE IS ERROR LINE
summary(ARIMAfit)
```

Also tell me how I can forecast for the next 48 days. I know how to forecast using simple `auto.arima` using the argument `n.ahead` but I don't know how to do it when the argument `xreg` is used.

Comment: Make sure you consider different days-of-week effects, different months-of-the-the year effects, level shift effects, local time trend effects , lead and lag effects around holidays/events , particular days-of-the-month effects , particular weeks-of-the-month effects , anomalous data points , long-weekend effects etc.. The data you are attempting to analyze in statistical sense is in the "deep end of the pool" so to speak thus simple methods/solutions will probably be deficient.otherwise you may "drown"

Comment: @IrishStat Can you please tell me what model to use if you have these many variables as you mentioned above. I saw your post in another topic that we can have 29 dummy var for days of week and hours of day. But, not sure how to handle these many variables.

Comment: I will look at your data when I get some free time

Answer (score 6):

Basically what caused the issue is the line `ts(data[1:96,4],start=1, end=96,frequency =7 )`, when you specify both start and end with `frequency = 7`, `R` is trying multiply the series so that it has a length of 96 weeks.

Recall `R` defines the start and end time in seasons (weeks in your case). Since you are fitting daily data, only specifying `start = 0` or `start = 1` should be sufficient.

Instead of running `View(saledata)`, try to use `saledata` to debug yourself and you can see wrong length of time series is outputted .

```
Start = c(1, 1) 
End = c(96, 1)
```

When you do ARIMA forecast with `xreg`, basically you will need to create a matrix `newxreg` for your next 48 days with the same structure as `xreg`, then specify `newxreg = newxreg` in the `forecast` function. A good habit for the `xreg` and `newxreg` matrix would be to include a `Day` column that acts as an ordering for the data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!