# Statistical method for analysing time series with correlated datasets

Tags: time-series, correlation, pca

I have a time series of different physical measurements. One of these, lets call it **X**, is determined by the others, $Y_1$...$Y_n$, through various physical processes (which are complex and not fully known). There is no influence of **X** on **Y**. The **Y** parameters are all caused by the same source, so they are correlated to various degrees. Some of these correlations are close to 1 or -1.

I am looking for a statistical method to analyze the impact of the different parameters on **X**.

**PCA** was suggested, but I have not used it before and from what I read it seems not well suited to the problem because of the correlation between the input parameters.

It might be possible to reduce the **Y**s to a combined parameter for each physical process (where correlation is lowest between them) and then use **PCA**, but I would be interested if there is a statistical method better suited to my problem, where I can use all parameters. Maybe someone here has an idea?

Comment: You should apply PCA on Y, and then check correlation of different factors to X.

Comment: Thats a good point actually, thanks. Maybe I should do this with all subsets of parameters that relate to the same physical process.

Answer (score 1):

ARIMAX
Here is a case where it has been used:
https://forecasters.org/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/7-2a51b93047891f1ec3608bdbd77ca58d/2013/07/Kongcharoen_Chaleampong_ISF2013.pdf

And there has been a discussion here, on how to do it in R:
[How to fit an ARIMAX-model with R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18375/how-to-fit-an-arimax-model-with-r)

Comment: Your reference showed no concern given to detecting and incorporating unknown deterministic structure causing pulses/level shifts/local time trends or seasonal pules OR possible changes in either error variance or parameters over time. Probably because they didn't have access to good tools.

Comment: True, when using ARMA-models, one needs to make the time series stationary. It is an art by itself and best results are often made by hand. Most automatic methods tend to give bad results.

Comment: I agree that there has to be some intelligent/assumption checking device whether it be an experienced hand/mind or an advanced software agent OR both