# How do I model the variation over time?

Tags: time-varying-covariate

**The data:** Each year, during the months from January to July, a select number of plants had a certain "thing" measured. Each month, this was done almost every day for some plants, and maybe weekly or so, for other plants. This was done for 5 years, and for each year, a new selection of plants were measured (since the ones from the previous year were dead at that point).

**Question:** How do I model the variation over time and potential correlation structures?

So far, my only idea is to use "Year" and "Month" as factors, and e.g. use "Year + Month + Year*Month" in my regression equation. Then "plant" could be a random effect.

But, is this too simple? What would you do?

Comment: in addition to the commenter's suggestion of ARIMAX, Distributed lag models might also be worth checking

Answer (score 0):

I would use a time series model for this type of analysis. That is, I would consider the data you've gathered as a broken, cyclical series of measurements. Specifically, since you're trying to measure the effect of a certain, presumably non-time-series-based "thing", I would use [ARIMAX](http://rzbl04.biblio.etc.tu-bs.de:8080/docportal/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/DocPortal_derivate_00011234/DISS_Lee_100605.pdf), which is a time series model that can incorporate the effects of exogenous variables (the 'x' in ARIMAX).

If you're trying to measure the difference between plant *species* or *treatments* of the *same* plant species (for example), you could use [ARIMAX](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18375/how-to-fit-an-arimax-model-with-r) to attempt to measure the impact of the treatment or species difference on growth rate. If you wanted to include other variables to control out their impact, such as precipitation and/or temperature, that would be enabled by the use of ARIMAX as well.