# Fitting a Multivariate ARIMA Model (in R)

Tags: r, time-series, arima, box-jenkins

I've been working on a high school project attempting to determine whether or not there exists a relationship (and if it exists, information on the strength and duration of the relationship) between stock market data and election polls (both in time series format, n=250).  While I'm moderately familiar on how to fit an ARIMA Model to a univariate time series using the Box-Jenkins approach, I've only encountered confusion when attempting to fit a model incorporating two variables.

Another response to a question similar to mine recommended using a transfer function, though I don't know if that would be applicable in my case as the goal is more to reveal information about a potential relationship, not necessarily to derive an exact formula linking the two series to be used for prediction.  Implementing a bivariate ARIMA model in R appears to be as easy as simply adding an additional series, yet there seems to be surprisingly little literature on this or how to interpret such a model.

Comment: Maybe you could try the var model (vector auto-regression model), it can deal with multiple variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fitting a multivariate ARIMA model with R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18314/fitting-a-multivariate-arima-model-with-r)

Answer (score 0):

You can start by reviewing a very basic ( and largely presumptive ) tutorial here https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/75/ . Review [How to include control variables in an Intervention analysis with ARIMA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176736/how-to-include-control-variables-in-an-intervention-analysis-with-arima/176800#176800) where I contributed to the discussion. The issue is to develop the relationship in a robust manner where anomalies do not distort.