# Multivariate Box-Jenkins in Python

Tags: time-series, python, arima, multivariate-analysis, fitting

I have different time series of hourly measures

1. ENERGY_PRICE (What we want to predict)
2. ENERGY PRODUCTION
3. ENERGY DEMAND
4. SOLAR RADIATION
5. WIND SPEED

There's some seasonality in the ENERGY PRICE, more specifically daily, weekly and yearly.

From what I read, it is not easy to model a series with various levels of seasonality using ARIMA ([Source](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18523/156678)).

As the goal is to predict one of the series from the others, @RobHyndman says that what I want is

> a transfer function or ARMAX model.

How should one model and fit ARIMA/ARIMAX with multivariable time series?

Ideally, are there Python implementations of it?

---

I have seen various questions with R, but none with Python.

• [Fitting a multivariate ARIMA model with R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18314/156678)

• [How to fit an ARIMAX-model with R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18375/156678)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You describe a multivariate time series.
You can use the VAR model, which basically extends the ARIMA model to a multivariate case.
VAR model is implemented in Python via `statsmodel` library.
You can try and look on your case a multivariate time series and also try using each feature or a group of them as exogenous variables to better explain one of the dependent metric.